# Error: unable to get local issuer certificate while running yarn command

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg

I have my own private npm registry `http://something`. I installed yarn and trying to run following command.

```
yarn
```

But it is giving following error.

```
Trace: 
  Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
      at Error (native)
      at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1017:38)
      at emitNone (events.js:67:13)
      at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:166:7)
      at TLSSocket._init.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:582:8)
      at TLSWrap.ssl.onclienthello.ssl.oncertcb.ssl.onnewsession.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:424:38)
```

I found couple of github issue and resolution as well.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/841
https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/commit/b0611a6ee5220b0b1e955b271b6140640158f96c (Available in 0.16.0)

Looks like i have to set `strict-ssl` to false in yarn config. I am unable to find exactly how can I do that. I tried giving option in following ways in package.json but didn't work.

1)

```
{
config: {
"strict-ssl": false
}
}
```

2)

```
{
"strict-ssl": false
}
```

But still I am getting same error. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

There is possibility that you are getting the error because you are running behind a proxy server. To fix this, open Node.js command prompt; type and execute the following command:

```
yarn config set "strict-ssl" false -g
```

For new versions use this command
`yarn config set enableStrictSsl false -g`

Comment: However, note that `-g` means it is set *globally*. To be a little safer, one could leave it off and run </br> `yarn config set "strict-ssl" false` </br> only if and when needed.

Comment: `export NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=/path/to/your/CA/cert.pem` is a better approach.

Answer (score 18):

Realised that config needs to get into `.yarnrc` file. I have set following to get it worked.

```
cafile null
strict-ssl false
```

Also please note that yarn also takes config options from `.npmrc` file as well.

Comment: I get an error regarding the cafile, but this DOES work - only if you put it inside the .yarnrc file, NOT inside the .npmrc file.

Comment: @raingod Did you get the error, `error Could not open cafile: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/project/dir/null'` ?

Answer (score 12):

The command has been updated. The command is now:

```
yarn config set enableStrictSsl false
```

Answer (score 1):

Those who are struggling like me with this error and unable to find yarn file searching `.yarnrc` file.

1. `brew install yarn` will install `yarn` at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/yarn/`
2. from the root of your project, run: `yarn config set enableStrictSsl false`
3. this will create `.yarnrc` file at `/Users/ur_user_name/.yarnrc`
4. now, open this file and paste what @thecodejack has given.

Mine looks like;

```
# THIS IS AN AUTOGENERATED FILE. DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE DIRECTLY.
# yarn lockfile v1


cafile null
enableStrictSsl false
lastUpdateCheck 1694717327033
strict-ssl false
```

and then i did `yarn` on my root project, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was a corrupted installation of node.

Uninstalling all related: node, npm, nvm, yarn; and reinstalling the packages anew solved the problem.